# Spring boot microservice memory usage

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, jprofiler

I have a spring boot jar file running in Amazon ec2 .
It do very basics thing take small entity from database build url from entity and call third party api .that's it. but it taking memory of almost 2gb sometimes . number of request also like 100 per day.
when i try with j profiler it showing some 200mb usage but linux showing 1400mB idle what might be the issue? how to track it.
[image: linux terminal]

[image: jprofiler data]

Comment: The image of the jprofiler shows, that you are watching the HEAP space, which is at ~250MB. Did you checkt the other spaces? What are their numbers?

Comment: do you have enabled actuator ? you can capture metrics using that as well and it shows you exactly how much your app is consuming

Comment: other means code ,meta data size, othe type of heap ? those are like 20-50mb only

Comment: What is your -Xmx value?